# EF 4.1 Referential integrity error

Tags: c#, .net, exception, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have the following classes:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
}

public class Survey
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsFinished { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserAnswer> UserAnswers { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class UserAnswer
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid SurveyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }

    public Guid QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

    public Guid AnswerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Answer Answer { get; set; }
 }
```

In my datacontext I have defined:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>().HasRequired(s => s.Person).WithOptional();
 modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>().HasMany(s => s.UserAnswers).WithRequired(a => a.Survey).HasForeignKey(a => a.SurveyId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

**Update:**

When I execute this code:

```
var surveyRepository = new SurveyRepository();
foreach (var userAnswer in userAnswers)
{
    survey.UserAnswers.Add(userAnswer);
}
surveyRepository.InsertOrUpdate(survey);
surveyRepository.Save();
```

I get the following error:

> A referential integrity constraint
>   violation occurred: The property
>   values that define the referential
>   constraints are not consistent between
>   principal and dependent objects in the
>   relationship.

Comment: What error did you get and when?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, try this way

```
 var surveyRepository = new SurveyRepository();
 foreach (var userAnswer in userAnswers)
 {
+    userAnswer.SurveyId = Survey.Id;
     survey.UserAnswers.Add(userAnswer);
 }
 surveyRepository.InsertOrUpdate(survey);
 surveyRepository.Save();
```

Comment: In my case it's a many to many issue. There are `Business` entity, and `Category` entity. I want each business to have multiple `Category`s, how do I attach them, using their `CategoryID`s?

Comment: @Shimmy `category.BusinessId = Business.Id` or `business.Categories.Add(category)`?

Comment: If `Business` exists and the `Id` is known to you, use it, otherwise just go with `Add`, but I think you're covered in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I know that is late but maybe this could be useful for someone. What about trying this?

```
var surveyRepository = new SurveyRepository();
surveyRepository.InsertOrUpdate(survey);
foreach (var userAnswer in userAnswers)
{
   survey.UserAnswers.Add(userAnswer);
}
surveyRepository.Save();
```

Recently I had that "*A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.*" error when I was editing an entity with children.

This was my code at the beginning:

```
myAction.ActionUserNameAssignations.Clear();

string[] sSelectedValues = CheckBoxListHelper.GetAllIds(collection, "CheckBox_UserName_", true).ToArray();
foreach (string userName in sSelectedValues)
{
   ActionUserNameAssignation assignation = new ActionUserNameAssignation { ActionId = myAction.ActionId, UserName = userName };
   myAction.ActionUserNameAssignations.Add(assignation);
}

db.Actions.Attach(myAction);
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myAction, EntityState.Modified);
db.SaveChanges();
```

And this is my code at the end, working fine:

```
db.Actions.Attach(myAction);
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myAction, EntityState.Modified);

myAction.ActionUserNameAssignations.Clear();

string[] sSelectedValues = CheckBoxListHelper.GetAllIds(collection, "CheckBox_UserName_", true).ToArray();
foreach (string userName in sSelectedValues)
{
   ActionUserNameAssignation assignation = new ActionUserNameAssignation { ActionId = myAction.ActionId, UserName = userName };
   myAction.ActionUserNameAssignations.Add(assignation);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

As you can see, the difference is basically Attaching the entity to the context at the beginning. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

When defining your model, you don't need to specify the Referential Id properties EF will create these in the database for you.

Change your UserAnswer model to

```
public class UserAnswer
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

    public virtual Answer Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nope that's not it, I have some other classes where I used keys and they work fine. I removed the key and still the same error. Thx though for the answer