# Updating object with related entities from detached state

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

When I query from the entity framework I always query in a detached state so that the records retrieved can be stored in cache for subsequent requests.

Right now I have a form that the user can edit which contains a parent record, and then two lists of parent records.

When the data is POSTed to the server, I take my view models and map them into the entity framework objects using AutoMapper.  The data looks fine; AutoMapper is mapping the data correctly.

When I attach the object so that I can update it, an exception is thrown:  `A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship`.

```
public static void UpdateOrder(ShippingOrder shippingOrder) {
    using (OrderEntity orderContext = new OrderEntity()) {
        //Exception happens here
        orderContext.ShippingOrders.Attach(shippingOrder);
        //Update the order itself; mark the order has being modified so the EF will update it.
        orderContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(shippingOrder, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
        //Perform the update.
        orderContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The EntityFramework (EF) seems to think that my keys aren't lining up, but I'm not sure what isn't correct.  The foreign key property does have the correct value, so I'm not sure what it's checking.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You might try something like this:

```
ShippingOrder existingShippingOrder = orderContext.ShippingOrders.Find(shippingOrder.ID);
orderContext.Entry(existingShippingOrder ).CurrentValues.SetValues(shippingOrder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
orderContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(shippingOrder, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
```

try this

```
orderContext.Entry(ShippingOrder).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: I'm not actually hitting that code.  The call on Attach results in the exception.

Comment: @Ek0nomik - When you debug, is the main key for the ShippingOrder null? I am curious if you are making sure to use `@Html.HiddenFor()` in your view's form.

Comment: The property that is actually the primary key in my table has a value.  However, the EntityKey property (which belongs to the Entity Framework base class) is showing a null value.

Comment: @Ek0nomik - This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015843/ef-4-1-referential-integrity-error

Comment: I had looked at that question already.  All of my properties are mapping correctly.  The property that is the foreign key has the correct value, and the property on the parent object that is the primary key has the correct value.  I feel like there is some base property that isn't being set correctly.

Comment: @Ek0nomik - Sorry, I am not sure what else it would be :(

Answer (score 0):

as explained [**here**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx)

> Insert or update pattern A common pattern for some applications is to
>   either Add an entity as new (resulting in a database insert) or Attach
>   an entity as existing and mark it as modified (resulting in a database
>   update) depending on the value of the primary key. For example, when
>   using database generated integer primary keys it is common to treat an
>   entity with a zero key as new and an entity with a non-zero key as
>   existing. This pattern can be achieved by setting the entity state
>   based on a check of the primary key value. For example:

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(DbContext context, Unicorn unicorn)
{
    context.Entry(unicorn).State = unicorn.Id == 0 ?
                                   EntityState.Added :
                                   EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

you can try

```
public static void UpdateOrder(ShippingOrder shippingOrder) {
    using (OrderEntity orderContext = new OrderEntity()) {       
        orderContext.Entry(shippingOrder).State = shippingOrder.Id==0?
                                                  EntityState.Added :
                                                  EntityState.Modified;

        orderContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

for `ObjectContext` class you can try

```
 public static void UpdateOrder(ShippingOrder shippingOrder) {
        using (OrderEntity orderContext = new OrderEntity()) {                  
            orderContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(shippingOrder, EntityState.Modified);    
            orderContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What version of the EF are you using?  I don't have a `Entry` method available on my context.

Comment: the link i refered to uses `DBContext` if you dont have the entry method then you must be using the `ObjectContext` class

Comment: updated the answer, that was what you were trying to do but attaching the modified object to the context without changing its state to modified throws the refrential integrity exception as the object state was not  modified it was treated as insert so the conflict occurs